# ¿Cómo puedo capturar un índice con JavaScript en una vista de listado en RoR?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Tengo la siguiente vista `index.slim` con código JS.

```
- ind = 0
- enlace = []
h1 Posts
table
    thead
        tr
            th Content
    tbody
        - @posts.each_with_index do |post,i|
            - ind = i
            - enlace[i] = "https://midominio.com/#{i}"
            tr
                td= post.content
                td
                    a.mx-1.btn.btn-sm.btn-outline-warning href="javascript:copiaURL();" Copiar URL
                td= i

javascript:
    function copiaURL() {
        var aux = document.createElement("input");
        aux.setAttribute("value","#{enlace[ind]}");
        document.body.appendChild(aux);
        aux.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.body.removeChild(aux);
        alert("URL copiada\n#{enlace[ind]}");
    }
```

Tengo un dominio de un cliente con ciertos parámetros, para efectos de la pregunta resumo los parametros con el índice del helper each_with_index, el problema que tengo es que me trae el último valor del arreglo y no me trae la selección que hice, adjunto una imagen que representa el problema que tengo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciono el índice 4 (puede ser cualquier de la lista) y siempre me trae el último.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me seleccione el índice que quiero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás mezclando variables de tu template slim con javascript, que son evaluadas en distintos momentos.

En otras palabras, estás iterando en `@posts.each_with_index` donde cada ciclo le asigna un valor distinto a a tu variable `ind` siendo 15 el último valor asignado. Luego FUERA del bloque de iteración, estás asignando `enlace[ind]`, o sea, `enlace[15]` a tu js. De hecho, si vas a revisar tu código fuente en el explorador, verás que siempre va a imprimir lo mismo, porque en el js resultante ya fue evaluado como:

```
alert("URL copiada\nhttps://midominio.com/15");
```

Una posible solución, sería algo como:

```
a.mx-1.btn.btn-sm.btn-outline-warning href="#" onclick="copiaURL('#{enlace[i]}')" Copiar URL
```

Lo que te generaría links del tipo `onclick="copiaURL('https://midominio.com/1')"`.
Luego, en la función recibir el parámetro como:

```
function copiaURL(url) {
    var aux = document.createElement("input");
    aux.setAttribute("value",url);
    document.body.appendChild(aux);
    aux.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(aux);
    alert(`URL copiada\n${url}`);
}
```